# The catch_error_str function isn't catching errors when the input is a integer. - Python

Tags: python

Please don't be too harsh because I'm new to coding. The problem I'm having is that the function catch_error_str does not work. For example, when I enter "2" as an input then it says last_name is 2 instead of catching the error.

```
def catch_error_str():
    unvalid = True
    while unvalid:
        try:
            string = str(input())
            unvalid = False
            return string
        except ValueError:
            print("You must not enter any numbers")

def surname ():
    print("What is the surname of the lead booker ")
    last_name = catch_error_str()
    print(last_name)

print("Welcome to Copington Adventure Theme Park's automated ticket system\nplease press any button to see the ticket prices.")
enter = input()
print("\nAdult tickets are £20 each \nChild tickets are £12 each \nSenior citizen tickets are £11 each")
surname()
```

Answer (score 2):

Python don't have a problem to covert a number to a string and because of that, there is no error rasing.
You can try

```
def catch_error_str():
    unvalid = True
    while unvalid:
        try:            
            string = str(input())
            if not string.isalpha():
               raise ValueError
            unvalid = False
            return string
        except ValueError:
            print("You must not enter any numbers")
```

The `isalpha()` method of string will check if the input not containing numbers and if so it will raise the value error.

Answer (score 0):

The value that is returned from `Input()` is of type `str` therefore, the conversion won't generate an error that you can catch with `ValueError`. Instead you should try to check the `type()` of the variable. Also, you are requiring the input within the try. I would use something like this:

```
def catch_error_str():
    unvalid = True
    while unvalid:
        string = input()
        try:
            string = float(string)
            print("You must not enter any numbers")
        except ValueError:
            unvalid = False
            return string
```

Since floats/ints can be converted to strings without any problem, I'm facing the problem the other way around. I am trying to convert it into a float, if I'm able to, it's because the value is numeric, hence the error. If I am not able to, then that means it will generate ValueError because it is text

Answer (score 0):

Input returns a string even if the user input is a digit.

```
name = input(“Enter last name: “)
if name.isdigit():
    unvalid = True
```

Answer (score 0):

If the prompt argument is present, it is written to standard output without a trailing newline. The function then reads a line from input, ***converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline)***, and returns that. When EOF is read, EOFError is raised.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input